# How can I find the max(RowID)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query and I use `Row_Number()`.

I want to select max(RowID) values, how can I do this.

```
select * 
from 
(
    select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by A.Name order by A.Name) AS RowID,  
    --**there are some joins and some where clauses**
) B
where RowID=1
order by Created desc
```

If QueryB can include `order by Created desc` I can select `RowId=1` and the issue is fixed. But when I try to this, I get an error.

So, how can I get the max(RowID) values?

Comment: Please explain why instead of order by a.name desc you are using order by created desc?

Comment: A have to get data which have newest created date @KaziMohammadAliNur

Comment: Since you accepted a result it seems that your problem has been resolved already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the correct `ORDER BY` clause in the `ROW_NUMBER()` function call:

```
select * 
from (
   select 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A.Name ORDER BY A.Created DESC) AS RowID,  
      -- columns ...
      -- FROM ...
      -- JOIN ...
) B
where B.RowID = 1
```